# Is there a general equation for the signal velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, speed-of-light, dispersion, phase-velocity

The phase velocity is defined as $v_{ph} = \frac{w}{k}$ and the group velocity as $v_{g} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial k}$. Both can exceed $c$ in some situations. The velocity than can't exceed $c$ is called the [signal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_velocity). Does the [signal velocity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath210/kmath210.htm) have a general form like the phase or group velocity, or is it only defined depending on context?

Answer (score 1):

A simple formula (that is not trivial, see below) does not exist. It is actually quite well explained on the page you link in your question and I quote here

> The problem with these stories is that the group velocity corresponds to the actual signal velocity only under conditions of normal dispersion, or, more generally, under conditions when the group velocity is less than the phase velocity. In other circumstances, the group velocity does not necessarily represent the actual propagation speed of any information or energy.

I would now speculate that the best answer is a trivial answer like this:
$$ v_{signal} = L / T$$ where L is the distance between sender and receiver and T is the time it takes for an observable modulation of the signal carrier to travel from sender to the receiver.